# Conditional scaling based on parameters

Tags: anylogic

I have a 3D object inside an Agent Type and what I want to do is to have the Agent's size/ scale change depending on a parameter. What I initially thought was to include code in the 3D object's "Additional Scale" dynamic value option, like this:

```
if(parameter==X){
  (this.setScale = 0.15);
}else{(this.setScale = 0.10);
}
```

But it isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use conditional operators instead of if/else:

```
parameter==X ? 0.15 : 0.1;
```

Put that code on additional scale. It's equivalent to your if else statement.

Comment: Thank you, that works!!
Would you mind helping me with a follow-up question.. what if I have 4 conditions in my parameter?

Comment: then you make a function that returns a boolean and you call the function in the additional scale... in the function you can use if statements and your function will take parameter as your argument